# Yocto/Bitbake Path Variable for Append File Directory

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, yocto, bitbake

So I am using a .bbappend file in a layer I have created and in that layer I also have some additional local files that I want to install.

The problem is I am not sure what the Yocto variable is that correctly represents the directory where my bbappend file is located. Variables like "THISDIR" end up pointing to the original recipe directory - not the append one in my layer. How can I best do this without putting some type of absolute path?

Answer (score 1):

Copy your files to present dir where the `.bb` or `.bbappend` file is present. and add follow line
`hello.bbappend`

```
FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}:"    
SRC_URI += "file://yourfile"
do_install_append(){
      install -d ${D}/some-dest-dir
      install -m 0644 ${S}/yourfile ${D}/some-dest-dir/
}
```

here `THIS` dir means you are telling to bitbake the files are present in the dir where the  `.bb` or `.bbappend` file is present.

e.g: meta-hellolayer 
example/
   |_ hello.c
   |_ hello.bbappend

Now the example dir is `THIS` dir in .bbappend file.

`Note`: Make sure you need to add your `layer path(meta-helolayer)` to `build/conf/bblayer.conf`

Comment: This is what I tried already, it is not working. The problem I am having is if I use "${THISDIR}:" in my .bbappend, it does not reflect the directory of my bbappend in my layer but rather the directory of the original recipe.

`e.g.
meta-mycustom-layer
...
|_ some-recipe.bbappend
|_ myfile`


`meta-original-layer
...
|_ some-recipe.bb`

Bitbake is searching for "myfile" in the "meta-original-layer" tree because THISDIR is reflecting that path and not the path of where the bbappend is located. FYI I am running Morty.

Comment: So I figured out part of the issue - I wasn't using the "immediate expansion" operator as the YOCTO manual suggests (":=" vs. "="). So now the path is correct, however it still can't find my file. Note that I am trying to copy the file directly in the task function (i.e. `install -m 0644 myfile ${D}/someinstalldir`). I can make this work if I instead set the "URI" and then copy from the workdir. What is the correct way to do this using my original method?

Comment: post your recipe then we can able to modify in a correct way

Comment: make sure you need to add your recipe .bb path in build/conf/bblayer.conf file.